# One column displays only one field, the rest calculate from all applicable records

Tags: php, mysql

Back again I'm afraid!

I have this SQL Query - populating a table.

```
echo SQLResultTable("SELECT SalesExec, COUNT(SalesExec)AS 'Total<br/> Checks', $AverageScore, `SUM(Autofails) AS 'Total <br/>AutoFails', $AverageAutofails FROM Data_Table WHERE BranchManager = '$BM'");`
```

In the database, I currently have 3 records.  2 for Sales Exec A, 1 for Sales Exec2.

The output form the above, is producing one row in a table. with just Sales Exec1's name.  However all the other fields are adding up / averaging etc, all 3 records values.

How do I get the table to produce the proper 2 rows I need with the averages/counts/sums etc just applying to the record that relates to that Sales Exec?

To get the table working, I snagged this function from a different site, that seems to work lovely other than this issue.

```
function SQLResultTable($Query)
{
    $host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "Quality_Monitoring";
    $link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());      //build MySQL Link
    mysql_select_db($db) or die('Could not select database');        //select database
    $Table = "";  //initialize table variable

    $Table.= "<table border='1' style=\"border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center; font-size: small; cellspacing: 5px; \">"; //Open HTML Table

    $Result = mysql_query($Query); //Execute the query
    if(mysql_error())
    {
        $Table.= "<tr><td>MySQL ERROR: " . mysql_error() . "</td></tr>";
    }
    else
    {
        //Header Row with Field Names
        $NumFields = mysql_num_fields($Result);
        $Table.= "<tr style=\"background-color: #000066; text-align: center; color: #FFFFFF;\">";
        for ($i=0; $i < $NumFields; $i++)
        {     
            $Table.= "<th>" . mysql_field_name($Result, $i) . "</th>"; 
        }
        $Table.= "</tr>";

        //Loop thru results
        $RowCt = 0; //Row Counter
        while($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result))
        {
            //Alternate colors for rows
            if($RowCt++ % 2 == 0) $Style = "background-color: #00CCCC;";
            else $Style = "background-color: #CCCCCC;";

            $Table.= "<tr style=\"$Style\">";
            //Loop thru each field
            foreach($Row as $field => $value)
            {
                $Table.= "<td>$value</td>";
            }
            $Table.= "</tr>";
        }
       // $Table.= "<tr style=\"background-color: #000066; color: #FFFFFF;\"><td colspan='$NumFields'>Query Returned " . mysql_num_rows($Result) . " records</td></tr>";
    }
    $Table.= "</table>";

    return $Table;

}

?>
```

Any help appreciated, cheers!

Comment: You should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL statement makes use of aggregate functions `COUNT(), SUM()` but has no `GROUP BY`.  `GROUP BY SalesExec`. Because MySQL is lenient about the presence and contents of the `GROUP BY` clause, it will return one row, probably with the first `SalesExec`, but with aggregates calculated over *all* `SalesExec`, which is not a meaningful result.

```
echo SQLResultTable("
  SELECT SalesExec, COUNT(SalesExec)AS 'Total<br/> Checks', $AverageScore, `SUM(Autofails) AS 'Total <br/>AutoFails', $AverageAutofails 
  FROM Data_Table 
  WHERE BranchManager = '$BM' 
  GROUP BY SalesExec
");`
```

Comment: PERFECT.  Thankyou, exactly how you described it.  Many Thanks.